# Publish to random port and return port in docker-py

Tags: python, python-3.x, docker

How can I replicate `docker run -P` in `docker-py`? I'd like to publish a single exposed port to a random port, then retrieve the exposed port in my code. I see `{'2222/tcp': None}` in the docs, but I can't quite see how to retrieve the port mappings from the `Container` object.

Comment: Did you try it with the `host_config` param while creating the container?

Comment: I'm currently not able to try executing code. `host_config` seems to allow publishing to random ports, but the issue I'm trying to solve is in retrieving the port published _to_

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the badly-documented `Container.attrs` is what you're looking for. Here's an example from a random stopped container on my system:

```
>>> client.containers.get('c7dcb410ba03').attrs['Config']['ExposedPorts']
{'80/tcp': {}}
```

The value of `attrs` appears to be the same as, or at least very similar to, the output of `docker container inspect`.